# Getting data from url(i.e. ID, etc)by using javascript and sending it to a database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, database

I'm a beginner programmer and i have been trying to solve this problem for 3 days now. I've been trying google and w3 but so far no luck and wanted to my luck here.

I need to get the the ID from a url (www.example.com/index.php?id=name). I've been studying how to do the html method but no luck there as well. The code that my boss gave me is messy and i can't read all of them. I'm sorry for asking you this ind of question and forgive my lack of knowledge. I also need to send it to a database.

The code in progress.

```
if(attemp>3){


alert("Account has been locked. Maximum (3) attempts reached!");

window.location.href="index.php?id="+u+"&#toregister";
```

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1409399

Comment: if you are using PHP then you can use the global (`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`) variables to get the ID parameter

Comment: share your code here

Comment: @Martin. I'm using javascript but is it easy when i do that in php?

Comment: My problem is kinda like this 
 <at the main thread edited>
Once a user fail 3 times a php?id=name appear. This happens in javascript and i've been thinking of switching to php but people says her that it is impossible. I'm pulling my hair out because i don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: in PHP on the page where you are trying to access the URL parameter it is as easy as using `$param = $_POST["id"];`